# complement of the intersection in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, intersection

I'm using Oracle SQL and i have a basic question regarding `join` command.

I have 5 tables. Each one of them has the same column as a primary key: `ID (int)`. Lets look at the following queries:

```
select count(*) from table_a - 100 records
select count(*) from table_c - 200 records
select count(*) from table_c - 150 records
select count(*) from table_d - 100 records
select count(*) from table_e - 120 records
```

---

```
select * -- 88 records
 from table_a a
  inner join table b
    on a.id = b.id
  inner join table c
    on a.id = c.id
  inner join table d
    on a.id = d.id
  inner join table e
    on a.id = e.id
```

In this case,  many records are failing to be included in the output if one of the tables is not including the certain ID (even if the rest of them are included). How can i know what are these "bad" records? It's actually the complement of the intersection i think.

I want to know what are the problematic records and tables of each case. For example: ID 123 is a "bad" records since it's not included in table_c, but included in the rest of the tables. ID 321 is a problematic records since it's included in all of the tables except table_d.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [symmetric difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) between all your tables.

To solve that kind of problem without being too clever, you need a [`FULL OUTER JOIN ... USING`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3174):

```
SELECT id
    FROM table_a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_c USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_d USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_e USING(id) 
WHERE table_a.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_b.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_c.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_d.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_e.ROWID IS NULL;
```

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` will return all rows that satisfy the join condition (like an ordinary `JOIN`) as well as all rows without corresponding rows. The `USING` clause embed an implicit `COALESCE` on the equijoin column.

---

An other option would be to use an [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29):

```
SELECT id
    FROM table_a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_c USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_d USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_e USING(id) 
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT id
        FROM table_a
        INNER JOIN table_b USING(id) 
        INNER JOIN table_c USING(id) 
        INNER JOIN table_d USING(id) 
        INNER JOIN table_e USING(id) 
)
```

Basically, this will build the union all sets minus the intersection of all sets.

Graphically, you can compare the `INNER JOIN`  and the `OUTER JOIN` (on 3 tables only for ease of representation):

[image: INNER JOIN][image: FULL OUTER JOIN]

---

Given that test case:

> ```
> ID    TABLE_A TABLE_B TABLE_C TABLE_D TABLE_E
> 1     *       -       -       -       -
> 2     -       *       *       *       *
> 3     *       -       -       *       -
> 4     *       *       *       *       *
> ```
>
> <sub>`*` value in the table `-` missing entry</sub>

Both queries will produce:

```
ID
1
3
2
```

---

If you want tabular result, you might adapt one of these query by adding a bunch of `CASE` expressions. Something like that:

```
SELECT ID,
    CASE when table_a.rowid is not null then 1 else 0 END table_a,
    CASE when table_b.rowid is not null then 1 else 0 END table_b,
    CASE when table_c.rowid is not null then 1 else 0 END table_c,
    CASE when table_d.rowid is not null then 1 else 0 END table_d,
    CASE when table_e.rowid is not null then 1 else 0 END table_e
FROM table_a
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_b USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_c USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_d USING(id) 
    FULL OUTER JOIN table_e USING(id) 
WHERE table_a.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_b.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_c.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_d.ROWID IS NULL
   OR table_e.ROWID IS NULL;
```

Producing:

> ```
> ID    TABLE_A TABLE_B TABLE_C TABLE_D TABLE_E
> 1     1       0       0       0       0
> 3     1       0       0       1       0
> 2     0       1       1       1       1
> ```
>
> <sub>`1` value in the table `0` missing entry</sub>

Comment: I've just tried it. Your query gives a reasonable output. Thanks. Any chance to make the output as Allan did?

Comment: @user3928712 As a matter of fact, I've mostly did it yesterday to build my "sample table". I've copied it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Working great!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following query

```
 SELECT id, COUNT(id) as id_num FROM (
 SELECT id FROM table_a
 UNION
 SELECT id FROM table_b
 UNION
 SELECT id FROM table_c
 UNION
 SELECT id FROM table_d
 UNION
 SELECT id FROM table_e
 ) 
GROUP BY id HAVING id_num <5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
        SELECT id FROM (
SELECT id FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT id FROM table_b
UNION
SELECT id FROM table_c
UNION
SELECT id FROM table_d
UNION
SELECT id FROM table_e
) result
WHERE id NOT IN ( select a.id from table_a a
        inner join table_b b
        on a.id = b.id
        inner join table_c c
        on a.id = c.id
        inner join table_d d
        on a.id = d.id
        inner join table_e e
        on a.id = e.id )
```

Comment: Well, sorry i didn't say it before, but i want to know what are the problematic records and tables of each case. For example: ID 123 is a "bad" records since it's not included in table_c, but included in the rest of the tables. ID 321 is a problematic records since it's included in all of the tables except table_d. I've just edited my question with an explanation.

Comment: Hey, I have provided a list of ids that are not in each table. Just play with it. Hint: "select id, 'wrong id' from table_a where id not ... " GL!

Comment: Your query is running too much time. My data is big (~60k records each table. The numbers above was just an example. The real numbers are ~60k).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use outer joins to determine which rows do not have matching primary (or unique) keys. For example, use a left join to find the the non-matching rows in table b in the following example:

```
select a.id from a left join b on a.id=b.id where b.id is null
```

conversely to find the non-matching rows in table a:

```
select b.id from a right join b on a.id=b.id where a.id is null
```

Comment: I know that, but it's suppose to give me the difference between two certain tables. I need the difference between all of the tables together. If i'll try to use left join between all of the tables, in order to find the differences, it would give me the difference between one table to the rest of the tables, and i need the difference between all of the tables together. I hope i'm clear enough (or maybe i'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

This solution will tell you which tables are missing rows for each `ID`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (SELECT id, 'table_a' AS table_name FROM table_a
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 'table_b' FROM table_b
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 'table_c' FROM table_c
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 'table_d' FROM table_d
          UNION ALL
          SELECT id, 'table_c' FROM table_e) PIVOT (COUNT (*)
                                             FOR table_name
                                             IN  ('table_a' AS table_a,
                                                 'table_b' AS table_b,
                                                 'table_c' AS table_c,
                                                 'table_d' AS table_d,
                                                 'table_e' AS table_e))
WHERE    table_a + table_b + table_c + table_d + table_e < 5
ORDER BY id
```

Sample result:

```
ID | TABLE_A | TABLE_B | TABLE_C | TABLE_D | TABLE_E
0  |       1 |       0 |       0 |       1 |       0
1  |       0 |       1 |       0 |       1 |       0
2  |       1 |       1 |       0 |       0 |       0
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it tomorrow. I must leave the office now.

Comment: Hi. I've just tried it. You query gives me just a ~300 records, while Sylvain Leroux query gives me ~11k records which is much more reasonable number. Any idea why?

Comment: In the sample data I created, all of Sylvain's queries give me the same number of rows as my query. I don't what would be different about your data that would cause the results to vary.